# How to read a tag from csproj in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core, csproj

I need to get the value of version tag placed in csproj from Dockerfile. Then I will be able to push my package to nuget with new version that i get from csproj. How can i get it?

my csproj :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.0.0-beta.6</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to get value within Dockerfile then you can try this

```
COPY cspro /cspro
RUN cat /cspro | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Version>)[^<]+" >> /version_tag.txt
RUN cat /version_tag.txt
```

you can then read version from  `version_tag.txt` this file.

```
Step 4/5 : RUN cat /cspro | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Version>)[^<]+" >> /version_tag.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0ba70a54a82d
Step 5/5 : RUN cat /version_tag.txt
 ---> Running in 8c5785bd8911
1.0.0-beta.6
```